# React not updating element, but creating new one with same reactid

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I'm having some trouble with React in Meteor.

So I have these lines in my React class' return statement

```
{this.renderRegisterButton()}
```

The corresponding function is this

```
  renderRegisterButton: function() {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
      if (this.data.tournament.ongoing || this.data.tournament.date_finished) {
        return ''
      } else {
        activeTournament = Meteor.players.getActiveTournament(Meteor.user()._id);
        if (activeTournament) {
          if (activeTournament._id == this.data.tournament._id) {
            var playerStatus = Meteor.tournaments.findTournamentStatus(this.data.tournament._id);
            if (playerStatus.status == 2) {
              return <div className="alert alert-success alert-checkedin" role="alert">You have succesfully checked in! Hang on tight, the tournament will start soon!</div>
            }
            else if (playerStatus.status == 1 && this.data.tournament.checkin_open) {
              return <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.attend}>Check in</button>
            }
            else if (playerStatus.status == 1 && !this.data.tournament.checkin_open) {
              if (playerStatus.status == 1) {
                return <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.removeAttend}>Withdraw</button>
              } else if (playerStatus.status != 1) {
                return <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.attend}>Sign up</button>
              }
            }
          } else {
            return (
              <div className="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                <strong>Warning!</strong> You're still active in another tournament, so you can't participate in this one. Finish your other tournament first
                before registering.
              </div>
            )
          }
        } else {
          if (Meteor.players.hasGameTag(Meteor.user()._id, this.data.tournament.game_id)) {
            return <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.attend}>Sign up</button>
          } else {
            return this.noGameTag();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

So, when the page is rendered and the tournament check-in phase is open and the player isn't checked in yet, I get this HTML spit out:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.3.0.0.2">Check in</button>
```

Which is correct. But when the player presses the check-in button, he gets correctly checked in, but my displayed HTML does not alter the check-in button. Instead, it just copies the new result as a new element and does nothing with my older element.

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-checkedin" role="alert" data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.3.0.0.2">You have succesfully checked in! Hang on tight, the tournament will start soon!</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.3.0.0.2">Check in</button>
```

So I end up with an element that has the same reactid, whereas it should've deleted the first button and replaced it in my html with my new div.

Any reason why this is happening? This is not the only place where this happens, but was the easiest to document.

It might just be that I'm not completely grasping the React way of doing things, so please correct me where needed!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my own issue, but it had nothing to do with the problem I described here.

Right above my `renderRegisterButton` in the `return` statement, I also had this line

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.data.tournament.description}}></p>
```

My tournament's description were some lines of HTML that also contained, among others, some `<p>` tags. 
Since nesting of `<p>` tags is not allowed, this managed to screw up my whole react-ecosystem.

Replacing the line with

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.data.tournament.description}}></div>
```

complete fixed my problem!